# Visual Studio and SQL Server . Cannot see Database into VIsual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, sql-server-express, visual-studio-express

So when I open Visual Studio 17 Community and try to add a new connection to a database , I hit Refresh but it doesnt detect my SQL Server Express Database.

[image]

In SQL Server Configuration Manager 2017 I see that it is running;
I can also connect to the database in SQL Server Management Tool 17.

What's the problem?

Comment: There are some reasons for that. To my mind check settings in SQL Server Configuration Manager. And also check the firewall settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be multiple reasons for that. You can just type `.\SQLEXPRESS` to connect (unless you changed the default instance name when you installed it).
To try to find out why it is not listed and fixed this, you must check:

- is SQL Browser service running
- your firewall don't block UDP traffic on port 1434
- in SQL Server Configuration Manager is TCP/IP network protocol enabled and your server allow remote connections

For more information take a look at [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2057/why-listing-all-of-your-sql-servers-does-not-always-work/) article.

Comment: SQL Browser is not running

Comment: the issue was same for me :)